# How to differentiate between various exception while calling a webservice in using .net?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-3.0

I am consuming one webservice, while consuming there can different types expception might occur depeninding on various situation like.. network failur, invalid soap data or exception from  serverside also might occur.

**How can I differntiate between these different excpetion?**

Because in my application, with these exceptions I need to update the various status Like: if network failure occurs Status will be "unable to connect webservice" so I can try after sometime later. If exception comes from Web server , no need to call/try again.

nRk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a try/catch block but with multiple catches for different exceptions? e.g.

```
try
{
    // webservice invocation
}
catch (SoapException ex)
{
    // Handle Soap exceptions
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    // Handle IOException
}
catch (Exception ex}
{
    // Handler of last resort - any exception not specifically handled above 
    // will be caught here
}
```